# Overriding .phtml in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides, phtml

I am overriding the `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\type\default.phtml`. For this I have copied this and pasted in my theme `app\design\frontend\Sm\clickboom\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\type\default.phtml`, But it is not working.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed **view** folde from your theme path, I think its issue of your theme template overriding. Please add **view** folder inside **product** folder.

New Path will be,

```
app\design\frontend\Sm\clickboom\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\type\default.phtml
```

Comment: Oh!... I forgot the path. Y'e Right Thankq.